# Communication protocols supported by Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, http, blob, mqtt, azure-blob-storage

I have tried to google and read as much Microsoft documentation as I can, but I do not seem to find a DIRECT answer to my doubt.

Does the Blob Storage in the Microsoft Azure Cloud support anything other than HTTP/HTTPS operations?

In the documentation about the IoT Hub I found that MQTT, HTTP and AMQT operations are supported, but I guess Blob STorage is not really part of the IoT Hub, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the Blob Storage in the Microsoft Azure Cloud support anything
>   other than HTTP/HTTPS operations?

Nope. For the most part, you access Blob Storage over HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Do you know which protocol is used in terms of Transport Layer? Is it TCP also? I thought TCP is only used for elements in the same network. I am very confused. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

And today, Azure Blob storage supports SFTP.

See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support